# how c handles the same variable name along different scopes?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction

I have following code

```
int main()
{
        static int x = 8;
        {
                static int x = 9;
        }
        printf("%d",x);
}
```

o/p-8

my doubt ,as per the rule says static variables are created only once and persist in memory.So if a variable with name x is persisted in memory then how can I able to create a new one.

kindly clear my doubt.I gone through google but how it is done,what I want in C programming .How compiler identifies both variables and how it is stored in memory.

T

Comment: Scope.  Scope.  Scope.  Scope...

Comment: ok,but how in memory it is,differentiate between two variable with same name.

Comment: why down vote for this .I hope it is only a concept that I missed.

Answer (score 2):

The disassemble output of `objdump` may give you some hints about how compiler (`gcc`, in this case) handle that situation:

```
$ objdump -d a.out
...
000000000040050c <main>:
  40050c:   55                      push   %rbp
  40050d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400510:   8b 05 fa 03 20 00       mov    0x2003fa(%rip),%eax        # 600910 <x.2163>
  400516:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
  400518:   bf fc 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005fc,%edi
  40051d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400522:   e8 b9 fe ff ff          callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
  400527:   8b 05 e7 03 20 00       mov    0x2003e7(%rip),%eax        # 600914 <x.2162>
  40052d:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
  40052f:   bf fc 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005fc,%edi
  400534:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400539:   e8 a2 fe ff ff          callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
  40053e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400543:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400544:   c3                      retq
```

Use `readelf`, we can find out that each `x` has its own symbol in the final executable file:

```
$ readelf -s a.out
...
45: 0000000000600910     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 x.2163
46: 0000000000600914     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   25 x.2162
```

Here is C code:

```
int main()
{
    static int x = 8;
    {
        static int x = 9;
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can u bit explain the assembly, I am new to that.

Comment: @pradipta Sorry, I cannot really understand those assembly codes. But it is quite clear that `gcc` gives each `x` a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, the compiler is *renaming* synonymous variables with different scopes.
Consider your file:

```
// file pradipta.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  static int x = 8;
  {
     static int x = 9;
  }
   printf ("%d\n", x);
}
```

then compile it (using GCC on Linux) with

```
 gcc -fdump-tree-all -O -Wall pradipta.c -o pradipta.bin
```

you then get a lot of `pradipta.c.[0-9]*t.*` files. They show you a *partial* (hence incomplete) dump of GCC representations. Some internal variables might be different but have the same name. Inside the compiler a variable is internally represented by some complex data structure (a `tree` node in GCC parlance, used inside `gimple` instructions), and you could have two different such structures with the same "printable" name.

You can also play with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to explore GCC internals (or customize its behavior by extending GCC with your MELT extensions).

Read also about *α-conversion* in the [λ-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

In practice, avoid synonymous variables of different nested scope. They make your code very unreadable by humans (even if compilers give a very precise and unambiguous meaning to your code). The `-Wall` option asks for all warnings, and you'll get a warning for such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Static values will persists during the functions calls.

But inside the same function scope alone matters. Put a printf inside the brace you will understand

```
int main()
{
        static int x = 8;
        {
                static int x = 9;
                **printf("%d",x);**
        }
        printf("%d",x);
}
```

Comment: Then if I will define it above main.how that works ?

Comment: If you define it above main its like a global variable, but since its static its only visible in the current .c file.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are created once and persisted in memory for the scope of the variable.

when you use

```
{
     static int x = 9;
     printf("%d",x) // would print 9 only
}
```

This creates a new scope and `x` is different from the `x` which is defined outside the braces.

scope can be created with braces,functions,file

If static variable is declared in global space then it is persistent across the entire file.

But also remember local scope variable is given preference over global variables with same name.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that a scope is created with each opening { and closed with each closing }. And that, for each new scope, the name of the variable gets prefixed (mentally) with the name of the scope (which can be assimilated to the name of the function or, for anonymous constructs like the one in your example, with a generic "scope1", "scope2", "scope3" sequence.

So, basically, there you define TWO variables, not one:

static int main.x = 8;

and

static int main.scope1.x = 9;

Both of these are static, but they have (for the compiler and the logic of the program) different names and act like different variables. Only their shortened name is the same, "x", and this is what confuses you, but the variables are in fact different. They respect what you say about "static", but without conflicting.

One word of warning: inside "scope1", the variable "main.scope1.x" hides the variable "main.x".

Bear in mind that this "renaming" using scopes names is merely an analogy and not the real thing. Still, I hope it helps in understanding the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A theoretical compiler can keep a *stack* of encountered symbols. When parsing a '{', the compiler can put this separator in the stack and when encountering '}' symbol, it will remove all the symbols between the last '{' ... '}' area.

When the compiler parses some symbol, it can simply delve deeper to the symbol stack to locate a match or announce an error.

At each crucial point of parsing this file, this compiler would have a symbol stack of:

```
main  main   main    main    main     main    main
      {      {       {       {        {
             x       x       x        x
                     {       {
                             x
```

This approach would actually map quite closely to legacy implementations of c-compilers -- the x-es would be placed to stack in reality too.